# .header { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; } this header.css file not showing any effect what will be the trouble?

Tags: reactjs

.header {     display: flex;     justify-content: space-between; }
Am building a tinder-clone but that file is having no effect in browser what will be the problem?

Comment: The code `.header { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }` is correct and not sufficient to reproduce your issue. Can you provide a code snippet? Did you import the CSS file in your component?

Comment: import React from 'react'
import "./Header.CSS"
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import ForumIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Forum';
function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            
                <PersonIcon />
                <h2>i am a header </h2>
                <ForumIcon />

            
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header
this is my header.js file

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-flex-zxwel?file=/src/App.tsx). Can you create a sandbox to reproduce your issue?